# Как возможно реализовать такое?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы h1 (Текст по середине) был как-бы привязан к фону. Из этого вытекает еще одна проблема, тут можно увидеть что буква О является как был элементом объектива. Решить нужно две задачи:1. Нужно чтоб при уменьшении ширины экрана текст шел как бы в паре с фоновым изображением. 2. Нужно чтоб буква О была отдельно кастомизирована? Как такое можно реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отрисовать буквы в SVG (чтобы это был `path`) и на фон `image` с изображением линзы.

Comment: А что если это должно быть заголовком h1? С точки зрения семантики это будет правильным решением делать текст в svg?

Comment: Посмотрите, например, как сделан заголовок у Инстаграма, там изображение с текстом в `h1`, сам текст скрыт от глаз, а для семантики он существует.

Comment: Понял, благодарю за ответ